# Building with emma maven project with a local repository

Tags: java, maven, repository, code-coverage, emma

I have the following layout

```
ThinClientManager
    |- src
    |   |- *source projects*
    |- repo
    |   |- com
    |       |- example
    |           |-*folders for maven created libraries. which contain the jar files required*
    |- target
    |- pom.xml
```

If I try to build the project from Jenkins, it does not find the packages declared within the Jar files in repo/com/example

If I try to run mvn emma:emma here is the output. I cannot find any code coverage reports within the target directory, apart from coverage.em

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ThinClientManager 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:emma (default-cli) @ ThinClientManager >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ThinClientManager ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 15 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ThinClientManager ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument (default-cli) @ ThinClientManager --    -
[INFO] Instrumenting classes with EMMA
processing instrumentation path ...
instrumentation path processed in 438 ms
[51 class(es) instrumented, 18 resource(s) copied]
metadata merged into     [O:\Sources\GroupAPT\Workplace\AdminTools\ThinClientManager\target\coverage.em] {in 98 ms}
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @     ThinClientManager ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory     O:\Sources\GroupAPT\Workplace\AdminTools\ThinClientManager\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @     ThinClientManager ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ ThinClientManager ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:emma (default-cli) @ ThinClientManager <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:emma (default-cli) @ ThinClientManager ---
processing input files ...
1 file(s) read and merged in 11 ms
nothing to do: no runtime coverage data found in any of the data files
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.154 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-04-11T12:20:45+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/224M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here Is the contents of pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ThinClientManager</groupId>
<artifactId>ThinClientManager</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ThinClientManager</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source />
                    <target />
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <reportFormat>xml</reportFormat>
                    <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/emma/classes</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-report-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>


<repositories>
    <!--other repositories if any -->
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>EAAdmin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>hlset</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>hlsetutil</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>tool</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You have two different issues - it is good to post them as separate questions

Comment: Why no code coverage reports?  No tests are compiled/run.  Perhaps `<testSourceDirectory>` needs to be set.

Comment: What is the error in jenkins?

Comment: @Raghuram Jenkins fails at finding the packages which are in the jar files in the local repository. I believe that once the packages are correctly found, emma might have a correctly compiled version to run.